# Unity storing an item in c#

Tags: c#, arrays, unity-game-engine

so I have 100 items that I need to store in some sort of array.
Each item has an att, def, cost, lvl, name and id(array key) value

What would be the best way to store them, keep in mind that i will need to sort the att and def values in descending order. While I have easily done this with php I am having some trouble with c#.

IF anyone could help provide a working example with just a couple of items that would be great thanks.

I am using unity and c#

Comment: Generic List and some Linq code should be enough to solve all the problems stated in your question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define a structure to store all the attribute:

```
class Enemy 
{
    public int Attack { get; set; }
    public int Defend { get; set; }
    public int Cost { get; set; }
    public ....
}
```

Then store all in a list:

```
var enemies = new List<Enemy>();
...
```

You can sort the enemies by anything

```
var sortedEnemies = enemies.OrderBy(item => item.Attack).ToList();
```